# WSO2 ESB NHttp vs HTTP Servlet Transport

Tags: rest, wso2, httprequest, wso2-esb

i have developed a custom mediator and i want to try publish it as a REST service con my WSO2 ESB 4.7.0.
Once i created the REST API, the ESB publishes it on the 8280 port.
On the client side, the POST REST call needs to specify some http parameters that i need to recover later in the mediator by this code:

```
org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MsgContext;
axis2MsgContext =  ((Axis2MessageContext) synapseMsgContext).getAxis2MessageContext();
HttpServletRequest obj = (HttpServletRequest)axis2MsgContext.getProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLETREQUEST);

if (obj != null) {
    System.out.println("Method :"+ obj.getMethod());
    System.out.println("Content-type :" +obj.getContentType());
    System.out.println("Content-length :"+obj.getContentLength());
    System.out.println("Remote addtress"+obj.getSession().getLastAccessedTime());  
}
```

The object i get is always null
. 
That's probably because on 8280 ESB uses the NHttp transport.

In what way can i solve this problem?

Have i to activate the HTTP Servlet Transport? How can i do this? By installing the WSO2 Application Server inside the WSO2 ESB (i ve done this, but how can i specify that i want a service to be exposed on 9763 port?)?

What's the difference between HTTP and NHTTP? Does the ESB performance get lower?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the WSO2ESB to listen to multiple ports.

By default it uses 8280, You can change this or add another listener.

This can be done by editing wso2esb-4.8.0\repository\conf\axis2\axis2.xml

```
 <transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener">
    <parameter name="port" locked="false">8280</parameter>
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
    <!--parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">hostname or IP address</parameter-->
    <!--parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://apachehost:port/somepath</parameter-->
    <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
    <!--<parameter name="priorityConfigFile" locked="false">location of priority configuration file</parameter>-->
</transportReceiver>
```

NHTTP or PTT are used to mediate the message.

Best Regards,
Malaka